# Using Hunspell with Unity (.net 2.0)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, hunspell

Hi is there somewhere solution for Hunspell for Unity(.net 2.0). I'm working on android platform.
I tried to implement [WeCantSpell.HuntSpell](https://github.com/aarondandy/WeCantSpell.Hunspell#encoding-issues)

But i get problem with encoding : "Encoding name 'ISO8859-1' not supported"
I researched a bit, and i saw it's using:  `"Encoding.RegisterProvider"` which is introduced in net 4.5.

When i tried to implement [nhunspell](http://www.crawler-lib.net/nhunspell) i got problem with initialisation. Actually problem with loading dll's.

```
ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null. Parameter name: path1 System.IO.Path.Combine (System.String path1, System.String path2) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mc‌​s/class/corlib/Syste‌​m.IO/Path.cs:138) NHunspell.MarshalHunspellDll.get_NativeDLLPath () NHunspell.MarshalHunspellDll.ReferenceNativeHunspellDll ()
```

Probably Hunspell is working only for windows platform? And only with net 4.5?

Are there any alternatives that use .dic and .aff files. I need this kind of solution, beacuse if i convert dic+aff to words list, for come countries files are 100MB+. From functionalities i only need to check if word exists in dict.

**SOLUTION:
Unity 2017 support .NET 4.5, i tried today beta version and it is working with Hunspell C# Port.**

Comment: If Hunspell is a .NET 4.5 dll then you will be unable to use this with Unity which runs on .NET 2.0, there's no solution.

Comment: There is always a solution or alternative. I could modify the source and just take functionality i need or create my own version from scratch but it's time consuming. I'm seeking someone who have experience with this to share some tips.

Comment: Depending on the complexity of "what you need" it's entirely possible that it's using a feature that's not available in .NET 2.0, that's you're real problem. You can *try* creating a bridge ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16336203/1663383)) but that may still not work, due to the differing .NET versions.

Comment: Yes i was thinking too about creating bridge with java port of hunspell. But i just realized unity will relese 2017 version with .NET 4.5 support. I just tried beta version and it's working with hunspell c# port.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question, for other guys who might get stuck like me:
Unity 2017 have .NET 4.5, i tried today beta version and it is working with Hunspell C# Port.

Comment: I saw mention of Unity 2017 the other day, but because it was still beta I didn't go look at its feature list. Nice that they've updated the underlying .NET version, that's big.

Comment: Yes, that is big step forward. Thanks anyway for helping me.