# Writing .Net window application in C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, window, i2c

I have a task to do: I have to write a graphical (window) application in .Net which is going to read temperature from the three sensors (namely MCP9808, SI7051 and STS31-DIS) connected via MCP2221 I2C/USB converter and display it on the screen.

There are some **requirements:** The app has to be graphically estetic, it has to have the some buttons (eg for the periodic read of the temperature) and it has to display a chart showing the temperature variations.

I know that .Net usually comes with C# but I've never used it before and also the libraries for the MCP2221 are for C++ as I believe.

Could anyone help me how to get down to this problem?

Comment: Why do you need to use .Net?

Comment: I don't know. That's what was told during the description of the task by my tutor. I believe they want this app to be compatible with multiple platforms. **And aside from what was told. What would you recommend to use?**

Comment: I recommend talking to your instructor and ask for more instructions.

Comment: "get down to this problem" - which problem? At the moment there's no problem, just a task.

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772041/using-c-library-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to use .NET for your GUI (WPF or WinForms), you should consider [.NET interoperability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/interoperability-overview), which allows you to call C++ compiled code from your .NET code.

Here is another StackOverflow post that should help you:

[How to call C++ DLL in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332701/)

If you want to use C++ syntax only, there is also [C++/CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp).