# How to get profiler attached true in c# profiling?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, profiler

How to call cpp functions with correct parameters from c# code while developing c# profiler

Any help or comments are highly appreciable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332701/how-to-call-c-dll-in-c-sharp

Comment: Hi @RamilAliyev Thanks for ur reply. Actually I am in the middle way of creating a c# profiler. Got stuck in the cpp area, not able to find the exact code flow. I am using datadog code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call C++ DLL in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332701/how-to-call-c-dll-in-c-sharp)